# MultiList with Search not showing items for non-admins

Tags: templates, fieldtype

There is a related item that suggests providing read access to /sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Item Buckets Settings, which I've done.  That at least removes the loading icon from the left shuttle box, but does not yield any items.  I've simplified the source field down to just the search location:

```
StartSearchLocation={224EB5B1-B053-42F8-87EC-9680B8C4A317}
```

But still get zero results. An "&TemplateFilter={ID1}|{ID2}" etc. also does nothing to help.  Items show up fine when logged in as an admin user.  I feel like there are some other permissions that might make this work?

Sitecore version 8.2

Comment: Is your non admin user having read access to the folder/item {224EB5B1-B053-42F8-87EC-9680B8C4A317}.?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Not able to re-produce this.. i did try with normal folder and bucketed folder but working.. issue happening only when the user doesn't have read access to the folder/item.. Is there any customization in your instance, relevant to this.? Can you please update the Sitecore version as well.

Comment: As far as I know, no, there isn't any customization.  We are on 8.2

Comment: Thanks for updating the version in the question..

Comment: Could you able to compare the calls/query to your search provider, from admin and non-admin.? Also is there any error log in Sitecore general logs or search logs.

Comment: How would I compare them outside of viewing a field in the CMS?

Comment: fiddler or any web debugging tools will trace the calls and you can check the response.. Also sitecore logs should have something.. I did try re-produce in Sitecore 8.2 but it works as expected for non admin users.. May be share your non-admin user details as well, i mean the list of roles inherited in your non-admin user..

Comment: Ok, so this seems to be an issue just with our dev server, our staging server shows the items, so maybe a configuration issue?

Comment: comparing the config and sitecore assemblies [just to make sure nothing corrupted] will be the right way diagnose this..